# Exclude an element in descendant selector?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am wondering if there is any way of excluding an element after selecting a descendancy. Let's say we have this DOM :

```
    <div class="container">
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
        .
        .
        .
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
    </div>
```

Now, if we use the selectors like this :

```
$('.container p')
```

We'll get all the `<p>` tags/objects (let's say they are n tags/objects). What if I want to exclude the k-ranked p-tag/objects ? Therefore having my selector return only n-1 p-tags/objects ?

P.S : you might recommand to use the `id` attribute, but let's suppose I can't add an `id` to all the p-tags and that I might want to exclude the k or j ranked p-tag, at wish. Also, I know that this might be doable in JavaScript, but I am searching for a jQuery specific answer (though JavaScript might be good as a last resort).

**k-ranked** : k-ranked p-tag/object will be the k'th positionned p-tag starting count from 1 :

```
      <p></p>  <---> 1
      <p></p>  <---> 2
        .
        .
      <p></p>  <---> k 
        .
        .
      <p></p>  <---> n-1
      <p></p>  <---> n
```

Thanks.

Comment: take a look at `.filter` method

Comment: You can still use `.filter()` on your selection

Comment: What do you mean by ranks?

Comment: Or try combining `.nextUntil()` http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/ and `:nth-child()` http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: @BoltClock : by ranks I meant the node basically. "k-ranked" will be the the child number "k" of the div.

Comment: Do you think jQuery is __not__ javascript??

Comment: @code-jaff : lol, actually I know its JavaScript, but what I said is : _"but I am searching for a jQuery specific answer"_ ... I suppose you can see the difference ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to apply a style to some elements and you want to exclude some kth element of that type then you can use this:-

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("p:not(:eq(2))").css("border", "3px solid red");
    });
```

[**JS FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/K7JMj/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like that:

```
var $elements = $("div.container > p:not(:eq(2))");
```

But say something more about "n", "j", "k" indexes.

Comment: Explained the indexes. Any doc about that `p:not(:eq(2))` ? Beginner here, and google doesn't seem to point some good help.

Comment: @Gloserio: http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/, http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/. In general: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/.